# Delphi: How to get the Calling-function or function-I-am-in?

Tags: delphi

Is there any way to get the Calling-function (best) or function-I-am-in (2nd)? (for setting callbacks to that function)
I would rather not have to specify the name of the function I am calling from, everytime I do it. Note that these functions are class methods.

Here is what I am doing: (and don't like)

```
procedure TX.SetMeTimer(FAnimate:Tproc);
begin
  Timer1.OnTimer:=FAnimate;
end; 

procedure TX.Animate1;
begin
  SetMeTimer(Animate1);
  DoSomething;
end;
procedure TX.Animate2;
begin
  SetMeTimer(Animate2);
  DoSomething;
end;
// to TXAnimate500, until you are sick of copying the function name....
```

This is what I would like it to look like: (Calling function approach)

```
procedure TX.StartReEntrantTimer(FAnimate:Tproc);
begin
  Timer1.OnTimer:=CallingFunction;
end; 

procedure TX.Animate;
begin
  SetMeTimer();
  DoSomething;
end;
```

Or function-I-am-in approach

```
procedure TX.StartReEntrantTimer(FAnimate:Tproc);
begin
  Timer1.OnTimer:=F;
end; 

procedure TX.Animate;
begin
  SetMeTimer(FunctionIamIn);
  DoSomething;
end;
```

Why? Doing a time-and-motion study on user working with this tool, putting wrong function name is a significant  error cause, and I would like to remove it.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this. And it doesn't make sense to reset `OnTimer` to the same value that `OnTimer` is already set to, every time `OnTimer` is called

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense, and a *time-and-motion study* on a developer's IDE is simply ludicrous. *Putting the wrong function name* is not an issue you're going to resolve with a *time-and-motion study* or silly code implementation of a useless *reset the method to the method I'm already in* idea. If you have developers who frequently put in the wrong function name, you're either using poor function names or hiring poor developers.

Comment: @Remy-Lebeau  I have amended the example to make the reason somewhat clearer: There are calls.

Comment: There are very many AnimateXX functions (may be thousands) which are self-referential, each of which can make many SetMeTimer type calls. All AnimateXX  are written and debugged by a "user". SetMe functions are programmer written. Neither execution efficiency nor programmer efficiency are objectives. "User" efficiency is. Think more excel situation than delphi.

Comment: @Ken-White  I doubt that the author of "The Mythical Man Month" would agree that "time-and-motion study on a developer's IDE is simply ludicrous". Back in the day, it was considered poor programming form for an identical item of information to be entered in multiple places. In this case the function name is that item. McDonalds got rich by "hiring poor developers" and removing the actual problems they have (time-and-motion studies). And, like McDonalds, AnimateXX are being written by the pimply and pubescent

Comment: And I will note that I have done this before (turbo-pascal 5), but it required inline asm (look up 2 levels in the return stack, get the call instruction and extract the address).

Comment: Fred Brooks was not talking about anything quite so mundane. Judging by the state of this question, I'd say his law looks as valid today as it ever was.

Comment: A timer's `OnTimer` event doesn't change by itself. Why does each animation method need to re-set the event? It seems to me that you don't need to keep calling `SetMeTimer` at all. Just assign `OnTimer` _once_ to whichever animation method you want to use, and then let the timer run. Only re-assign the event property when it actually needs to change. It doesn't look like it needs to change from _within_ an animation method.

Comment: *The Mythical Man Month* was written in the mid-1970s, when development tools were basically hammer and chisel on stone compared to tools we have today. Even it's latest update was two decades ago, and developer's tools have evolved drastically in that time. Citing an antiquated source as evidence that something is relevant today (especially in the areas of technology) is simply ludicrous. While some parts are certainly relevant, time-and-motion study on an IDE isn't, IMO, especially in the area of developers not being able to select the proper function to call.

Comment: @Ken-White I don't see that different tools change fundamental problems. "Where does the time go?" and "Why is this a problem?" and "how can I change things so you can do your job fastercand better", are timeless questions. A power-drill is faster than a hand-drill, but it can still be used more or less efficiently. And the difference is studying how it is actually being used, and making changes to improve that. I simply do not see that IDE's are some special case, or really that Programmers are special, and not like other production workers doing a labour intensive handicraft.

Answer (score 1):

The unit TestFramework.pas of the DUnit test code that comes with Delphi has a function CallerAddr which (in Delphi 2005) is implemented like this:

```
function CallerAddr: Pointer; {$IFNDEF CLR} assembler; {$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF CLR}
begin
  Result := nil;
 end;
{$ELSE}
const
  CallerIP = $4;
asm
   mov   eax, ebp
   call  IsBadPointer
   test  eax,eax
   jne   @@Error

   mov   eax, [ebp].CallerIP
   sub   eax, 5   // 5 bytes for call

   push  eax
   call  IsBadPointer
   test  eax,eax
   pop   eax
   je    @@Finish

@@Error:
   xor eax, eax
@@Finish:
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

(Later versions have been modified, so you should check the implementation of your own Delphi version.)

It is used to raise exceptions at the address of the calling method in DUnit tests. It should be possible to use it or at least adapt it to your purpose.

Note that this will likely only work for Win32 programs.

Comment: Thanks, I shall have a look.  I had thought that modern protections would be protecting the calling stack from the dataspace. However I worry that an asprin a day will not be sufficient to prevent a stroke if I ever have to do Intel assembler again.

Comment: I just now read your comment "And I will note that I have done this before (turbo-pascal 5), but it required inline asm (look up 2 levels in the return stack, get the call instruction and extract the address).". Note though that the above reads the return address from the current stack, so it points to the instruction after the function call. I am not sure if it is possible to repeat that for the next level because that would require knowledge about the stack used for local variables. Also, you'd need not just the return address but the call address and in addition, the data pointer.