# Delphi - Is there any easy/quick way to get the caller function address?

Tags: delphi

Is there any simple way (both on x86 and x64) to determine which function called the 
"test3" runtime? I try to find some short code, not whole frameworks (jedi's debug)

```
Program Test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

Procedure Test3;
Begin
// Detect caller here
End;

Procedure Test1;
Begin 
Test3;
End;

Procedure Test2;
Begin
Test3;
End;


Begin 
Test1;
Test2;
Readln;
End;
```

Comment: See [Delphi: How to get the Calling-function or function-I-am-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46749517/576719)

Comment: side note: Add logging to your application, then you wouldn't need this.

Comment: Delphi XE2 and later have a `System.ReturnAddress` intrinsic. In earlier versions, you would have to use inline assembly to get the return address.

Comment: whosrdaddy: This is a simplified example, call comes from any address outside the DLL, so cannot add logging to 3rd party apps/dlls.

Comment: Looks like System.ReturnAddress works x64, get good result if another dll/exe call my DLL. Now I just need to determine the ReturnAddress pointer belongs to which DLL/EXE (I'm on DX).